# Multiple Memberships and Web.Config folder access

Tags: asp.net, membership

I have an asp.net 4.0 website with multiple memberships

```
<membership defaultProvider="name1"
<add name="name1"
<add name="name2"
<add name="name3"
```

I am changing the membership for login successfully, so logging in is working. I have roles setup and working - GetRolesForUser is working. The login I am testing is in the created role - "Admin". I am using a custom membership provider class I created to switch the provider depending on passed in criteria to the login screen. I have this working great, however, I created a folder called "common" and put some webforms in it. I then created a web.config to allow access ONLY to the "Admin" role.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The admin logged in gets an HTTP 404 error when trying to access any webform in that directory. I remove the "deny" and it is now accessible. I check out his roles in code and it is linked to Admin. I look at

```
Membership.Provider.Name
```

and its pointing to the default config membership (name1), not the correct membership the user logged in as (name3).

My question is now, is the web.config in the "common" folder using the asp.net "Membership" as its lookup? How do I get around that by using multiple memberships, connections, and profiles for my different databases and logins?